# How to show min-max error in react hook forms?

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

Im using react hook forms to filter input between a minimum and maximum value. Code is successfully implemented but now the problem Im facing is, I was unable to figure out how to show the message to UI if user puts more or less than the accepted value.

```html
<input type="number" name='orderQuantity' required placeholder={product.minOrder} { ...register("orderQuantity", { min: minODR, max: maxODR }) } />
```

I want to display the error message before Submit button. Here is the full form code.

```html
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <div className="block lg:flex  gap-5">
    <div className="form-control w-full">
      <label className="label">
        <span className="label-text">Quantity</span>
      </label>
      <input type="number" name='orderQuantity' required placeholder={product.minOrder} className="input input-bordered w-full" {...register("orderQuantity", { min: minODR, max: maxODR } )} />
    </div>
    <div className="form-control w-full">
      <label className="label">
        <span className="label-text email">Phone:</span>
      </label>
      <input type="text" name='phone' placeholder='Active Number' className="input input-bordered w-full" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="form-control w-full">
    <label className="label">
      <span className="label-text email">Location:</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder='Delivery Location' name='location' className="input input-bordered w-full" />
  </div>
  <button type='submit' className="btn btn-block btn-primary mt-3 text-white">Place order</button>
</form>
```

[image: Form Screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to setup my validations in the useForm hook, using yup resolver is very easy and powerful. I'll give you and example:

```js
const {regiter, control, handleSubmit, formState:{errors, isValid}} = useForm({
   resolver: yup.object({
      orderQuantity: yup.number().min(10,'Min validation message').max(100, 'Max validation message')
   })
})
```

Also I use to set validation mode to 'onChange'

Below your input 'orderQuantity' you could render a span, p, or whatever tag you prefer to show the message, an example:

```js
{errors.orderQuantity?.message && <p>{errors.orderQuantity.message}</p>}
```

The above snippet will show the 'p' tag only if the form errors state contains a key for 'orderQuantity' if not, then the input is considered valid

EDIT: A better rendering for your input when using react-hook-form:

```js
<Controller control={control} name="orderQuantity" render={({field, fieldState: {isValid, error}}) => <><input {...field}/>{!isValid && <p>{error.message}</p>}</>}/>
```

Controller is a component from react-hook-form itself, control is the method returned above when used useForm hook, and now the component renderend inside Controller has direct access to its own state, so 'isValid' and 'error' refers to that component instead of to the whole form

Answer (score 0):

To display error messages using the built-in max, min, maxlength validators, you will need to define your error message using the format below, if you don't the validator would work but no message would be displayed to the user.

**"regularPrice" is the name of your form control**

```js
<input type = "text"
className = "form-control" {
    ...register("regularPrice", {
        required: "Field is required 
            (customizable)
        ", 
        max: {
            value: 5,
            message: "must be less than 5 (customizable)"
        },
        min: {
            value: 1,
            message: "must be greater than 1 (customizable)"
        },
        maxLength: {
            value: 50,
            message: "Max 50 is allowed"
        }
    })
}
/>
```

Reading your error message for each input could be done in several ways. To keep it simple you could have such;

```
<span>{errors?.['regularPrice']?.message?.toString()}<span> (if using 
typescript)

<span>{errors?.['regularPrice']?.message}<span> (if using javascript)
```